# Get GLSL uniform array length

Tags: c++, arrays, opengl, glsl

So I have this problem that

```
glGetActiveUniformsiv​(<program>, <ucount>, <indicesptr>, GL_UNIFORM_SIZE, <retptr>)
glGetActiveUniform(<program>, ...)
```

Returns always just 1 as uniform array length even if I declared an array of length 8 in the shader. Also I do access the array contents in the shader as the uniforms are otherwise reported okay by these funcs.

I think my driver (I have ATI Radeon 5750 HD and recent drivers) violates the GL 3.3 spec:

```
"If pname is UNIFORM_SIZE, then an array identifying the size of the uniforms
specified by the corresponding array of uniformIndices is returned. The sizes
returned  are in units of the type returned by a query of UNIFORM_TYPE. For active
uniforms that are arrays, the size is the number of active elements in the array; for
all other uniforms, the size is one."
```

Am I right so far or doesn't your driver report 1 as array length? It does not matter if the uniforms are in block or not. I still get just 1. The only option I have would be parsing the uniform names to get the maximum array index available. This will be complex as it must support all array phases in GLSL.
I need the array size in C++ program side to initialize enough resources for the shader.

Btw.. I could see that phase "all (other) uniforms, the size is one" may be misleading for some folks..

Comment: You might want to enumerate all of the "active uniforms". I know that in many GLSL compilers (NV is particularly annoying when it comes to this), it generates multiple active uniforms (one for each array index). Something along the lines of `myArray[1]`, `myArray[2]`, etc.

Comment: Even if you DECLARE the array as length 8, if only ever USE element 0, the shader compiler might cut it down to size 1, as that is all that matters.

Comment: As I alredy said I do get back all 8 (or what ever amount) uniform array elements e.g array[0], array[1].. and so on. (and this seems to be the behaviour the spec requires) It is that the `glGetActiveUniform` doesn't report the correct array lenght at all.
Andon: well if driver chooses to report each array index as completly separate uniform that would explain the current behaviour as separate uniforms do have lenght of 1.
So what should I do to get that array name and max index?

Comment: @JATothrim: That is a good question, my solution to a similar issue was to actually eliminate `glGetUniform (...)` altogether. My software builds a collection of uniforms per-program object by walking through all of the active uniforms after linking. Any part of the engine that refers to a uniform by name has to use an interface that matches the active uniforms reported by GLSL against the input name. This was needed to overcome an issue with NV's GLSL compiler that has since been fixed, but I found that it gave me much more control over static type matching and actually kept it this way.

Comment: Arrays were the most difficult type of uniform to handle correctly when I decided to bypass `glGetUniform (...)` and functions like it. Suffice it to say that if your OpenGL implementation is of the variety that reports `arrayName[0]`, `arrayName[1]`, `arrayName[2]` when you walk through all of the active uniforms one-by-one (NV does this), then each of this uniforms will have a size of 1. If it actually only lists `arrayName` without the individual subscript (AMD does this), then it will return the length of the array.

Comment: This is a mostly cosmetic issue related to how the active uniforms are reported, by the way; not how they are actually implemented. Behind the scenes you can still reference an individual element in an array of uniforms by offsetting from the base location for `array[0]` or `array`. It definitely brings up issues when you are trying to encapsulate shaders/programs in a C++ class and want to manually enumerate all of the uniforms the GLSL compiler did not eliminate after linking. I will see if I can dig up the relevant code I used for this purpose later tonight.

Comment: Well I solved this problem by parsing the returned uniform names. It realy is quite complex task to do. I now use the uniform arrays to apply multiple materials to my objects. I stream material id (index to the uniform array) as vertex attribute to fragment shader which then picks the right settings for the object dynamically. I render thousands of variable objects this way.